# как стереть вывод принта python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите битый час уже маюсь

```
    import datetime
import time
while 0 == 0:
    d = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(d[0:18])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
import time
while True:
    d = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(d[0:18], end = "\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```